# How can I use my tensorflow/keras CNN model to predict from my camera (that I loaded in) with this code?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, webcam

[code for predicting on live camera](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqa0Nqd29xY0xuVmVTTjEyMzRsVUFBTzRNckJfd3xBQ3Jtc0ttbEZvUTUzYjRYbk1yQ2JZYWRPU05zZjhhZ1MzSHl2VUNpclN6RTJnaGRzbTB2QnhzOWhpdlRiblh2aWUwSmNkOEJzOXA1Q09uaXhkeUNQdFBxd05IeWtLLTVXVW5Tc0dNMzVMX010VDh0d0c1Q21acw&q=https%3A%2F%2Fcolab.research.google.com%2Fdrive%2F1QnC7lV7oVFk5OZCm75fqbLAfD9qBy9bw%3Fusp%3Dsharing&v=YjWh7QvVH60)

It's fairly simple what I am trying to do, loading my tensorflow AI from file. trying to use it to predict on my live webcam (through google.colab).

I am trying to predict with the AI I made (using the code in the link), saved and loaded (using tensorflow: **model.save** and **load_model**)
I have a copy of this and I am loading in my own model instead like this:

```
model = load_model("/content/drive/MyDrive/aifolder") # Load from folder saved to.
```

they download theirs from online using:

```
#face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.samples.findFile(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'))
```

under the code titled **Webcam Videos**, at the very bottom, they start predicting with the AI at:

```
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray)
```

I replaced this line with my AI model like this:

```
#predictions = model.detectMultiScale(gray)  # ( code Commented out) 
predictions = model.predict(gray) #Predict through webcam
```

I am unsure how to calibrate this code to be suitable for my tensorflow AI. I really feel that I am missing something very simple to do this (like a simple command). I am a beginner so I am not sure what it should be.

edit:

I have loaded in my model using

```
model.load_model("filepath here")
```

and I have now done:

```
classes = model.predict(gray)
```

(Instead of the previous way that the cascade model was used) and I get this error:

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(32, 640).

I have tried changing the shape which I can change the "640", but I cannot find out how to change the number "32" so that I can process this into the first layer.

Comment: I think if I can load the saved model as a cv2, it would work. how would I do it?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74512971/how-do-i-load-a-saved-model-from-drive-with-cv2-cascadeclassifier

Comment: I have loaded in my model using .load_model and I have now done:

classes = model.predict(gray)
(Instead of the previous way that the cascade model was used)

and I get this error: 

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(32, 640).

I have tried changing the shape which I can change the "640", but I cannot find out how to change the number "32"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tensorflow.image.resize` API to resize the image. The error could be due to a shape mismatch between the Input Layer's shape and the shape of the image that is passed to the model while predicting.

```
import tensorflow as tf 

img=tf.keras.utils.load_img(path of the image)
img=tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
print(img.shape) # (272, 185)
# Resize the image
img=tf.image.resize(img,(224,224))
print(img.shape)# (224,224,3)
```

Then you can predict as follows after loading the model

```
classes = model.predict(img)
```

Thank you!

Comment: I get a mismatch with the file directory when inputting "/content/tulip.jpeg". I am unsure about that. I also decided to put this code before the prediction also if you find that relevant. Thankyou!

Comment: In place of "/content/tulip.jpeg", you need to pass the path of the image. Kindly try the modified answer above. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I tried that earlier (copying how the previous code sampled the frame). I will keep trying. Thanks!