# How do I load a saved model from drive with cv2? (CascadeClassifier)

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, opencv, cascade-classifier

I am trying to load my saved CNN model with cv2 the same way I managed to load this model.

```
# initialize the Haar Cascade face detection model
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.samples.findFile(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'))
```

I am trying to open it this way so I can use the code the previous model was used with.

```
model = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.findFile('/content/drive/MyDrive/aimodelfolder'))
```

Comment: CNNs aren't cascade classifiers. why should that even work?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74511932/how-can-i-use-my-tensorflow-keras-cnn-model-to-predict-from-my-camera-that-i-lo

Comment: Im not sure how to make it work if I am honest. I have a CNN model which can detect people, I am trying to take a frame from the camera and detect if there is a person in the frame or not. I am just unsure how I can do that using this type of model. I thought if I take the "gray" variable it could work. I have tried. when I do it it says that the shape isnt relevant for my layer which I am trying to solve as somewhere there is a "32" I am trying to get rid of.